# CSS select input where parent isn't 'classname'

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this rule in my stylesheet:

```
input:not([type='button']):not([type='submit']):not([type='checkbox']):not([type='radio']),
select {
    padding:8px;
    width:224px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

This targets all the text fields on my page but I need to prevent it affecting inputs which are inside an element with a certain class. I'm using ckeditor and need to not affect the fields in the dialog boxes that it creates - this means I can't just overwrite the rule afterwards.

I've tried adding `:not(.cke_editor_pageContent_dialog input)` but that doesn't work for obvious reasons. I can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere

Comment: Can't you just add a common class on them?

Comment: I can't believe I hadn't thought of that - yes I could, though there's quite a few places where I'd need to add it so it'd be good if there is a way to do it using :not()

Comment: Such a long and complicated selector will quickly become unmaintainable anyways. Might be easier and quicker to add those classes in the long run.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. Thanks for the suggestion, if you want to add an answer below I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a long and complicated selector will quickly become unmaintainable in the long run.

It would be much easier and cleaner to add a **common class** on the elements you want to style the same way.

```
.text-field {
    padding:8px;
    width:224px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The right approach might be to go with a "whitelist" approach instead of a "blacklist" approach (telling the browser what *not* to select).

For one thing, it avoids the problem you are experiencing. Also, the `:not()` selector does not work in IE8 or lower (not sure if that matters). Lastly (just a guess) I have to believe that complex `:not` statements are more expensive to evaluate.

I would suggest putting either explicit class names on the elements in question, or better yet, wrapping all the non-editor elements inside an element and using that as a style container.

```
<div class="myStyles">
    <!-- elements that should be styled -->
    <input type="text" />
</div>

.myStyles input[type="text"]{
    padding:8px;
    width:224px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

I realize that this may require more markup, but it will probably be easier to maintain in the long-term.

Answer (score 0):

I know the better answer has already been given, but just for the record, and to augment Tim's answer.

If you want to work with inputs that either have `type="text"` or don't have a `type` attribute at all, use this selector:

```
input:not([type]), input[type='text']
```